# Apache 2.4.51 bypass Basic Auth for specific query string

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess, http-basic-authentication

I need Basic Auth on my website, except if a specific hash is present in the URL.

- [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) => Authentication required
- [www.example.com/whatever](http://www.example.com/whatever) => Authentication required
- [www.example.com/whatever?hash=123456](http://www.example.com/whatever?hash=123456) => **No Authentication required**

```
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Dev"

<RequireAny>
    <RequireAll>
        Require expr %{QUERY_STRING} = 'hash=123456'
    </RequireAll>

    Require valid-user
</RequireAny>
```

Basic Auth works, but authentication is required even if `hash=123456` is in the URL. What am I doing wrong?

#### Update

Here is my entire `.htaccess` contents.

```
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Dev"
Require expr "%{QUERY_STRING} == 'hash=123456'"
Require valid-user
```

I hit [www.example.com/?hash=123456](http://www.example.com/?hash=123456) and it still requires me to authenticate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> Require expr %{QUERY_STRING} = 'hash=123456'
> ```

You would need to enclose the entire expression in double quotes. And it should be `==` (double equals) for a string comparison, not `=`.

You also shouldn't need any of the `RequireAny` and `RequireAll` containers since `RequireAny` is the implied default.

So, the following should be sufficient:

```
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Dev"
Require expr "%{QUERY_STRING} == 'hash=123456'"
Require valid-user
```

Note that the above is an exact string comparison. So, if there might be other query string parameters then you will need to use a regex. For example:

```
Require expr "%{QUERY_STRING} =~ /(^|&)hash=123456($|&)/"
```

---

Alternatively, use an `<If>` expression and only apply the HTTP authentication when `hash=123456` does *not* appear in the query string. For example:

```
<If "%{QUERY_STRING} !~ /(^|&)hash=123456($|&)/">
    AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Dev"
    Require valid-user
</If>
```

Comment: Are the double quotes around the expression mandatory? They are missing from most of the examples on the official documentation.

Comment: I have tried everything but it still doesn't work. Auth is required even if the hash is in the url.

Comment: I have tried this on another web root (same web server) and it works! So there is something funny going on on the web root of the previous website I was trying this on. Got to find out what it is.

Comment: I have found the issue. See my own answer. Thanks anyway for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that the `'` in `'hash=123456'` is part of the expression instead of being the quotes as you expect.

For exact match, try:

```
Require expr "%{QUERY_STRING} == hash=123456"
```

If you could have other parameters than `hash`, you might need regular expressions:

```
Require expr "%{QUERY_STRING} =~ /hash=123456/"
```

However, that would match `someparam=foo&anythinghash=12345678`, too. A possible fix for that:

```
Require expr "%{QUERY_STRING} =~ /(^|&)hash=123456($|&)/"
```

Comment: True for the quotes. I have tried with and without. I have tried all 3 solutions but none worked. 1) 500 Server Error 2) and 3) No error but still asks for authentication. Weird thing is that with solution 2) if I click "cancel" on the credentials popup, the site loads but without CSS/JS.

Comment: I have updated this based on the hints on the answer from @MrWhite.

Comment: Still no luck and I can't figure out what is wrong. I have tried everything, including with and without quotes (produces no error) and various versions of the regex and exact match. It still requires the auth.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing the check of the hash in my PHP controller and only added an `.htaccess` exception based on the `Request_URI` but even when doing that, I would still get the authentication prompt.

I then understood that my exception was OK but that the specific URI was requesting additional resources such as JS, CSS, fonts and image files that were **not** on the allowed URI, which is why I would still be required to authenticate.

My goal was that 2 specific URI would be fully accessible without authentication (`form/installation` and `form/vehicules`) so this is what I have done:

```
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Dev"

SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/(form/installation|form/vehicules) noauth=1
<RequireAny>
  Require env noauth
  Require env REDIRECT_noauth
  Require valid-user
</RequireAny>
<FilesMatch "\.(?i:css|js|svg|otf|png|jpe?g|ico)$">
    Require all granted
</FilesMatch>
```

Now, both URI are loading without requesting authentication, and with all the needed resources.